# Should I avoid nested functions?

Tags: javascript, function, performance, optimization, nested-function

Is this tree **nowadays**

"Try to avoid nested functions because they will always be **lazily parsed**, so they will be parsed repeatedly, and this will affect the performance"

so, should I use this

```
function fun() {
    function foo() {}
    foo();
}
```

or this

```
function foo() {}
function fun() {
    foo();
}
```

**Which one is better in terms of performance?**

Comment: From the given example the nesting choice is rather a matter of `foo`'s encapsulation/visibility than a (not really  existing) performance issue. Use the former if just `fun` is allowed to access and invoke `foo`. Use the latter in case `foo`'s scope is of no importance.

Comment: "*Is this tree nowadays*" - ???

Comment: No, nested functions are not getting parsed repeatedly. Yes, they might be parsed lazily, which is actually beneficial to performance. Yes, the function objects might get re-created on every execution of the outer function, which would negatively affect performance, but not by much. If anything, this would be a **premature micro-optimisation**. Focus on readability/maintainability first.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/